# how can I achieve the output for highlighting images in web app which retrieved from mysql server through php upon certain conditions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[This is the example of highlighting with svg applying to the image with status==1 from mysql column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZUN7.png)I am currently developing an web app which is linked to the android app from where images are uploaded.

I am retrieving the images from mysql database and the code is written in php for outputting the images in web app.

Below are my codes of php web app.

I am unable to highlight the images in the web app.

I dont know where I am lagging Please kindly help me through this.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <style>
      .myBox{    
        background:red;

      }
      .greenBox{
        background-color: red;
      }
      .redBox{
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style></head></html>

    <?php
    //action.php
    if(isset($_POST["action"]))
    {
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","indishare");
      if($_POST["action"] == "fetch")
      {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM upload_img ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

        $output = '';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

        {

          if($row['status'] == "1"){
            $colorClass = "greenBox";
          } else {
            $colorClass = "redBox";
          }


          $output .= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['file_name'] ).'" />

            <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger bt-xs delete" id="'.$row["id"].'">Delete</button>';

        }


        echo $output;

      }
    }
    if(isset($_POST["action"]))
    {
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","indishare");   
      if($_POST["action"] == "delete")
      {
        $query = "DELETE FROM upload_img WHERE id = '".$_POST["image_id"]."'";
        if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
        {
          echo 'Image Deleted from Database';
        }
      }
    }
    ?>



    Below are the parts of  html file code for loading the image in the web app.


    <div class="header">
      <h2>
        GALLERY
        <!--<small>All pictures taken from <a href="https://unsplash.com/" target="_blank">unsplash.com</a></small>-->
      </h2>
      <hr/>

      <div class="body">
        <div id="aniimated-thumbnials"  class="list-unstyled row clearfix" >
          <div class="myBox <?php echo $colorClass; ?>">

          </div>


        </div>

      </div>
    </div>







<script>  

$(document).ready(function(){

  fetch_data();

  function fetch_data()
  {
    var action = "fetch";
    $.ajax({
      url:"action.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{action:action},
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('.myBox').html(data);
      }
    })
  }

  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
    var image_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var action = "delete";
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this image?"))
      {
        $.ajax({
          url:"action.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{image_id:image_id, action:action},
          success:function(data)
          {
            alert(data);
            fetch_data();
          }
        })
      }
      else
        {
          return false;
        }
  });
});  

</script>
```

Comment: Firstly what do you mean by 'highlighting' the images? Secondly, please add a sample fo the actual HTML output. The PHP is not relevant to the problem

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: If the image is successfully displayed, and that is accomplished using jQuery, you could perhaps check out the `css()` and `toggleClass()` jQuery methods to add styling to your image on success.

Comment: I am stuck about applying if else condition. I've tried it in action.php file from where the image is being produced to the html document.